# Google spreadsheet script - move value to specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script

#### Problem

I want to copy a cell value to a specific cell. In this code, it should get a cell value (B!C1), then copy `getLastRow()` in 'A' tab sheet. At this moment, I want to copy cell value(B!C1) to C1 (for example). Also, it should increased +1 row to next copy(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1)

How do I solve this problem?

#### Code

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
   var source = ss.getRange ("B!C1");
   var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("A");
   var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
   source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
   //source.clear ();
}
```

#### I want to change

> 1.B sheet A1 cell value copy and paste A sheet C1
>
> 2.B sheet A1 cell value copy and paste A sheet C1+1
>
> 3.B sheet A1 cell value copy and paste A sheet C1+2

Comment: This line of code `var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);` will automatically get the next row in every run of the function. If you need something else, you have to state that clearly.

Comment: With this code or adding some code, I want to change per every function run,
B sheet A1 cell value copy and paste A sheet C1 ->B sheet A1 cell value copy and paste A sheet C2 ->B sheet A1 cell value copy and paste A sheet C3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
   var nCopies = 3; //number of rows you want to copy to
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
   var source = ss.getRange ("B!A1");
   var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("A");

   for(var i=1; i<=nCopies; i++) {
     var destRange = destSheet.getRange(i,3);
     source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
   }
}
```

It takes the content of cell `B!A1` and copies it to the third column (C) in sheet A, starting from the first row, and ending at row `nCopies`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do exactly? You want to achieve this in multiple function calls?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, but it is not what I want.
This is what exactly I want.
When it run moveValuesOnly(), it get cell value from "B!A1" and paste it  to "A!B8". Then next time, when it run function, "A!B8" will keep the value and paste cell value to "A!B9".
in my sheet "B!A1" will change when it run

1st function run : B!A1 = apple ,A!B8 = apple
2nd function run :  B!A1 = banana,  A!B8 = apple A!B9 = banana
3rd function run :  B!A1 = melon,  A!B8 = apple A!B9 = banana A!B10 = melon